# Why do the values of array elements are not getting printed and generating notice when put inside double quotes?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, echo, notice

As per my knowledge if PHP variables are echoed inside double quotes they get printed on screen.

For example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>    
  <?php
    $jumbo = "JumboJet";
    echo "$jumbo"; 
  ?>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Similarly, I tried to print array elements of a multi-dimensional array inside double quotes but instead of printing the array elements it's generating notice as **"Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground\demo.php on line 17"** in following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <?php
    $cars = array(
      array("Volvo",22,18),
      array("BMW",15,13),
      array("Saab",5,2),
      array("Land Rover",17,15)
    );

    for ($row = 0; $row < 4; $row++) {
      echo "<p><b>Row number $row</b></p>";
      echo "<ul>";
      for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++) {
        echo "<li>$cars[$row][$col]</li>";
      }
      echo "</ul>";
    }
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Whereas if I try with the code `echo "<li>".$cars[$row][$col]."</li>";` instead of code `echo "<li>$cars[$row][$col]</li>";` I get the desired output without any notice.

Why this is happening? Why the same thing that works for normal variable couldn't work on array elements?

Someone could please help me in this regard?

The desired output of above code is as below :

[image]

Comment: add curly braces - `echo "<li>{$cars[$row][$col]}</li>";` http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex *Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrap it in { and }.*

Comment: @Sean : Thanks for your help and it worked for me but would you please explain me Why does the same thing that work for normal variable couldn't work on array elements? Why there is a need to put curly braces around?Thank You, waiting for your reply!!!

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.simple -> *If a dollar sign ($) is encountered, the parser will greedily take as many tokens as possible to form a valid variable name.*. Since `$cars` is a valid variable name, the parser stops there, but since it is an array, it gives you the `Notice: Array to string conversion...`. The next line states -> *Enclose the variable name in curly braces to explicitly specify the end of the name.*  That is why for array values you need to wrap in curly braces so that parser gets `$cars[$row][$col]` and not just `$cars`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **complex syntax** to get around with this problem using double quotes.

Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax.
This can be achieved by surrounding the variable with curly braces`{}` as follows -

```
    echo "<li>{$cars[$row][$col]}</li>";
```

Answer (score -1):

@Hey All double quotes ("") data work as a constant string, it can not evalute the expression that's why the value of an array index unable to evalute 
But by {} braces you can evalue the expression in double quotes like understand the below one

```
<?php
    $arr = array(array("name" => "user2839497"));
    //echo "$arr[0]['name']"; // this is not the right way it will generate an error like array to string conversion
    echo "{$arr[0]['name']}"; // by using {}braces you can resolve your problem

?>
```